# How to handle cloud run websocket connection timeout server side

Tags: google-cloud-platform, websocket, google-cloud-run

Running a cloud run service which basically establishes a websocket connection to an endpoint (third party) which sends events for which I listen on the server. Unfortunately websocket connections are treated as long running https request by cloud run. Thus i need to reconnect at the 60 min timeout. What is the best way to do this server side (since i dont control the client)? schedule a new connection every 59 minutes and drop the old one? Also don't want to miss any events on the reconnection. Would appreciate any ideas:)

Implement scheduler, but not very elegant imo

Comment: You cannot reconnect on server side. You need to engineer your clients to do the reconnect, or watch the disconnect event.

Answer (score 2):

WebSockets requests are treated as long-running HTTP requests in Cloud Run. They are subject to request timeouts (currently up to 60 minutes and defaults to 5 minutes) even if your application server does not enforce any timeouts.

Accordingly, if the client keeps the connection open longer than the required timeout configured for the Cloud Run service, the client will be disconnected when the request times out.

Therefore, WebSockets **clients** connecting to Cloud Run **should handle reconnecting** to the server if the request times out or the server disconnects. You can achieve this in browser-based clients by using libraries such as [reconnecting-websocket](https://github.com/joewalnes/reconnecting-websocket/) or by handling "disconnect" events if you are using the [SocketIO](https://socket.io/docs/v3/server-socket-instance#disconnect) library.

Comment: I do not control the client connecting to cloud run